# How do I print a struct instance in the console without displaying it's whole stacktrace in Julia?

Tags: struct, printing, julia, instance

There are two Julia files :

**file1.jl**

```
struct MyStruct
    attribute :: String
end
```

**file2.jl**

```
module myModule
    include("file1.jl")
    println(MyStruct("a"))
end
```

When I execute **file2.jl**, it's supposed to print an instance of **MyStruct**

```
user@user-MS-7823:~$ julia cpsld/file2.jl
Main.myModule.MyStruct("a")
user@user-MS-7823:~$
```

I was expecting it to only print the struct name (so **MyStruct("a")**), however I got surprised as it also prints all the modules name, which is a bit annoying...
Is there any way not to print the modules along with the struct name?

Comment: There's something inconsistent: in the file you write about, there's no `module2`. Try restarting your REPL once.

Comment: Sorry, I've just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IOContext` like this:

```
module myModule
    struct MyStruct
        attribute :: String
    end
    println(IOContext(stdout, :module=>myModule), MyStruct("a"))
end
```

(the fact that you have definitions split into two files is irrelevant here)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Bogumił Kamiński for your solution.
The problem is that this only works for printing (ok, I know that's why I asked for lol).

Imagine I have three files.

**file1.jl**

```
module myFirstModule
    struct MyStruct
        attribute :: String
    end
end
```

**file2.jl**

```
module mySecondModule
    include("file1.jl")
    include("file3.jl")
    myThirdModule.hello(myFirstModule.MyStruct("a"))
end
```

**file3.jl**

```
module myThirdModule
    include("file1.jl")
    function hello(arg)
        println("argument : ", arg)
        println("isa test : ", isa(arg, myFirstModule.MyStruct))
    end
end
```

Well, there, the second module creates an instance of myStruct, and calls the "hello" function from the third module with that instance as an argument.

That is the console output :

```
argument : Main.mySecondModule.myFirstModule.MyStruct("a")
isa test : false
```

As you can see, the result of the isa test is **false**.

This acutally means that **arg**'s type isn't **myFirstModule.MyStruct**, but when I print **arg**, as you can see I'm getting this : `Main.mySecondModule.myFirstModule.MyStruct("a")`

Does it mean that **myFirstModule.MyStruct** != **Main.mySecondModule.myFirstModule.MyStruct** ?